# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67 when uploading video

Tags: php, laravel

[image: Picture 1 uploadscontroller]

[Picture 2 Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHnib.png)

[Picture 3 Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bCIy.png)

Hi,

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title when trying to upload a video using Laravel 5.2.

Images work correctly.

I've checked the PHP.ini settings of my MAMP server.

I'm using the form facade so I don't have to import token into my form.

I'm clueless, does anybody have suggestions what it might be?

```
<div class="container spark-screen">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Bestand uploaden</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::open(
                        array(
                            'url' => 'uploads',
                            'class' => 'form',
                            'novalidate' => 'novalidate',
                            'files' => true)) !!}

                        @include('uploadspanel.create_form')

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public function store(UploadRequest $request){
    $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = rand(11111111, 99999999). '.' . $extension;
    Input::file('file')->move(
      base_path().'/public/files/uploads/', $filename
    );
    $approved = $request['approved'];
    $fullPath = '/public/files/uploads/' . $filename;
    $upload = new Uploads(array(
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'format' => $extension,
        'path' => $fullPath,
        'approved' => $approved,
    ));
    $upload->save();
    $uploads = Uploads::orderBy('approved')->get();
    return view('uploadspanel.index', compact('uploads'));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting files to true? `Form::open(['files' => true])`

Comment: There is also a max limit on file size for uploading. Try increasing that one.

Comment: are you setting the csrf _token in the  form of uplaod ?? or not

Comment: He clearly states he is using the form facade.

Comment: i uploaded more pictures of my code, hopefully someone can help me. thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need the `enctype` property in your form. `files => true` handles that for you.

Comment: added code as rjdown requested

Comment: It seems like you're doing a POST or a PATCH/PUT request. Add the right `method` property to your form like this: `method` => `POST`

Comment: @Slence this is also not working :( still the same error. i expected that because, i only get this error when uploading video files. images, pages, docx, powerpoint are all working perfectly

Comment: Yes then it's most likely the file size. trying upping that in the config files of your webserver.

Comment: @Slence i allready upped that file size 
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
any other suggestions

Comment: Can you try with a very small video file?

Comment: @Slence will try! thanks for trying to help! really appreciate it

Comment: @Slence a really small video is working!! but i'm 100% certain i upped my php.ini to accept files of 100MB.  Am i missing anything?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with compression but that's just a wild guess. Glad you resolved it.

Comment: @Slence i still can't upload my "larger" file of 40MB. any suggestions on how i can get that to work?

Comment: post_max_size=1024M in your php.ini. Or any other value you see is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with MAMP settings. figured it out when i echo php_info();

then on line 6 or 7 followed the path to my php.ini
then changed the inputs again with another editor, saved it.

retart MAMP server

and done

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the token included in your form, go to your page and inspect it, you should see something like this:

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Th4yqxNa3w3ooVAxRcSgvMug7ZEPA6BtaUw4qRck">
```

if you don't then add it in your blade like this:

```
{{ Form::hidden("_token", csrf_token()) }}
```

Another issue you might have is in case you are submitting this form through an AJAX request, in that case, you would need to pass the token there too:

```
$.ajax({
    url  : '{{ route("your_route", optional_parameter) }}',
    type : "post",
    data : { '_token' : '{{ csrf_token() }}', 'var1' : var1 },
}).done(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your file which you are uploading is smaller than the max upload size but more than the POST_MAX_SIZE. 
The input is truncated at the POST_MAX_SIZE which means that the csrf token is lost.

You can change these values in php.ini file.