# How can i write validation for maximum video upload size in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, video, size

I have wrote following code inside my modal 
'video' => 'mimes:mp4,mov,ogg,qt |max:30000'.I can upload video of size below 3mb. when i tried to upload video of size grater than 3mb it showing following error.

TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

I have changed my php.ini file to raise the max fileupload size.Still i have the issue.How can i solve this issue?

Comment: This error for csrf token related please follow this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934906/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-53-in-laravel-5-1) hope this work for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53 in Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934906/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-53-in-laravel-5-1)

Comment: Please try with(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701274/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-67-when-uploading-video)

Answer (score 1):

This error is not about max-size. You have to add csrf field into form tag.

Insert this code into form label .

```
 {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are hitting a max size limit on POST data, which is causing it to just drop the inputs.

You can adjust your web server and php to a higher limit and see if it helps.

post_max_size in php.ini would be a good place to start.

**OR**

If you want to use CSRF in form then you have to add this line in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```